# terraform depends_on for provisioner file

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

i want data "template_file" in below terraform code to execute after provisioner "file" (basically ansible playbook) is copied to the ec2 instance. I am not able to successfully use "depends_on" in this scenario.  Can some one please help me how can i achieve this? below is the sample code snippet.

```
resource "aws_eip" "opendj-source-ami-eip" {
  instance = "${aws_instance.opendj-source-ami-server.id}"
  vpc = true
  connection {
    host = "${aws_eip.opendj-source-ami-eip.public_ip}"
    user                = "ubuntu"
    timeout = "3m"
    agent = false
    private_key         = "${file(var.private_key)}"
  }
  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "./${var.copy_password_file}"
    destination = "/home/ubuntu/${var.copy_password_file}"
  }
  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "./${var.ansible_playbook}"
    destination = "/home/ubuntu/${var.ansible_playbook}"
  }
}

data "template_file" "run-ansible-playbooks" {
  template =  <<-EOF
              #!/bin/bash
              ansible-playbook /home/ubuntu/${var.copy_password_file} && ansible-playbook /home/ubuntu/${var.ansible_playbook}
              EOF
  #depends_on = ["<< not sure what to put here>>"]
}
```

Comment: Your `template_file` block here doesn't seem to actually depend on the result of the provisioner, so I'm not sure why you want to defer rendering it until after the provisioner is complete. Is your goal here to execute the script produced by that template via SSH to the remote host?

Comment: Well, i am adding the scripts as cloud-init to ec2 instance user-data so that they get executed when ec2 instance comes up. 
`resource "aws_instance" "opendj-source-ami-server" {
  .....
  user_data = "${data.template_file.run-ansible-playbooks.rendered}"
  ....
}` It just that some time it fails complaining scripts not found, certainly its failing into catch22 situation i guess..

Comment: The `template_file` data source doesn't have any side-effects, so its _own_ rendering cannot fail as a result of missing scripts. Nothing in your example actually _runs_ that script, but I assume you have something else in your configuration that is running it.

Comment: To make error searchable: `Invalid depends_on reference`, `References in depends_on must be to a whole object (resource, etc), not to an attribute of an object`. The error appears when you use something like `depends_on=resource.aws_lambda_function.func_name`. Use `depends_on=aws_lambda_function.func_name` instead.

Answer (score 4):

The correct format for `depends_on` is pegged to the resource as a whole; so the format in your case would look like:

```
data "template_file" "run-ansible-playbooks" {
  template =  <<-EOF
              #!/bin/bash
              ansible-playbook /home/ubuntu/${var.copy_password_file} && ansible-playbook /home/ubuntu/${var.ansible_playbook}
              EOF
  depends_on = ["aws_eip.opendj-source-ami-eip"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks @TJ Biddle for your response. I did try that but tf started failing with this error: _Error asking for user input: 1 error(s) occurred:_

_* Cycle: module.vpc.data.template_file.run-ansible-playbooks, module.vpc.aws_instance.opendj-source-ami-server, module.vpc.aws_eip.opendj-source-ami-eip_ any other suggestions?